# Python - Selenium : Scroll down not working because of PopUp

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I am writing a python script using selenium to login to Facebook and then do some scrapping. For that purpose, **I have to scroll down to the bottom of the page. I think the pop that you can see in the picture is the cause of this.**
Here is the snippet of code which does the following thing

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/jatin.wadhwa.52/friends?source_ref=pb_friends_tl")
time.sleep(10)

element_new = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
element_new.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
element_new.send_keys(Keys.END)

#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
f = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul")
```

[image: Picture of Pop up on browser]

Comment: Don't try to scrape Facebook. You will be blocked sooner or later. Just use the API

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Adding this will resolve and woulndt allow any such pop ups.

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\jatin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)
```